# Proving that $\frac{a}{b}>\frac{a-1}{b-1},\; a<b$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants

Tags: inequality

I tried $\frac{a}{b}>\frac{a-1}{b-1}$

$a\left( b-1 \right)>b\left( a-1 \right)$

then this gives $a<b$ which is already given. Any ideas?

Comment: Which expression do you aim to use to prove the other expression, $\frac{a}{b}>\frac{a-1}{b-1}$ or $a<b$?

Comment: both; also $if\; a>b\; then\; \frac{a}{b}<\frac{a-1}{b-1}$ which i think would require similar proof

Comment: It's not clear at all what is supposed to be proven under what assumptions.

Comment: there's a comma there in the question; prove the first given the second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac ab-\dfrac{a-1}{b-1}=\dfrac{b-a}{b(b-1)}$$

If $b>0,b>a;$  $$\dfrac ab-\dfrac{a-1}{b-1}\text{ will be }>\text{ or }<0$$

according as $b-1>$ or $<0$

Comment: I see what you did..not sure how I missed that, but thanks. Also just a question: wouldn't $a$ and $b$ in this case be $>1$ (which is also $>0$ I know)?

Comment: @inspd, The expression will be $>0$ if $$b>a, b>0,b>a$$  $a$ can assume any value $<b$